# Dates per customer

Tags: mysql

**Customers** table:

```
|   id   |   name   |
---------------------
|   1    |   John   |
|   2    |   Mike   |
```

**Calendar** table:

```
|  date      |
--------------------
| 2015-01-01 |
| 2015-01-02 |
| 2015-01-03 |
```

---

**Question**: How can I get this result?

**Desired** result:

```
|  name   |  date      |
------------------------
|  John   | 2015-01-01 |
|  John   | 2015-01-02 |
|  John   | 2015-01-03 |
|  Mike   | 2015-01-01 |
|  Mike   | 2015-01-02 |
|  Mike   | 2015-01-03 |
```

Comment: The two answers below are identical, as EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS would demonstrate, so pick whichever you like. As a rule, we like to avoid comma join syntax, because it's archaic and doesn't play nicely in more complex queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    Customers.name, 
    Calendar.date
FROM Customers 
CROSS JOIN Calendar
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below query to get desired results

```
select t1.name as name,t2.date as date 
from Coustomers t1 
join Calendar t2 on 1=1
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But sorry I will choose the person who answered CROSS JOIN because I think that's the 'right way' and your answer is a hack.

Comment: @KenthJohnIsrael both ways are right, choose which ever you like. But please don't underestimate the one who is trying to help you.

Comment: @Shaharyar I didn't underestimate his answer, I'm actually very grateful from him for helping me.

Comment: thank you for better answer @Shaharyar i learned something today :)